# Slide div left and right repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a div which moves from the left hand side of the screen to the right, repeatedly. I want to make it look as if it is swinging on an axis. I have current code, however, sometimes when you load the page the div moves from the left to the right and then gets stuck trying to move to the right again.

```
   moveBlock: function(){
    var madeRight = false;
    $('.curBlock').css({"left": "2%"});
    intv = setInterval(function(){
        var curBlock = $('.curBlock');
        if(parseInt($(".curBlock")[0].style.left.replace("%", "")) < 42 && parseInt($(".curBlock")[0].style.left.replace("%", "")) > 1 && !madeRight){
            console.log("hi");
            $('.curBlock').css({"left": parseInt($(".curBlock")[0].style.left.replace("%", "")) + 1+"%"});
        }else if(parseInt($(".curBlock")[0].style.left.replace("%", "")) > 1 || parseInt($(".curBlock")[0].style.left.replace("%", "")) == 42){
            madeRight = true;
            $('.curBlock').css({"left": parseInt($(".curBlock")[0].style.left.replace("%", "")) - 1+"%"});
        }else{
            clearInterval(intv);
        }
    }, 50)
},
  processBlock: function(){
    setInterval(game.moveBlock(), 1000);
  }
```

Any help towards achieving this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks. :-)

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to make the post huge (I'm new here so just getting used to it). Whole file is here: http://welfordian.com/game/ however, if you'd prefer JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6rvbjmmz/

Answer (score 0):

Consider CSS animations:

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
  var element = document.getElementById("d1"); 
  document.body.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true)); 
  element.classList.toggle("sidetoside"); 
}, 2500);
```

```css
@keyframes slide {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

.sidetoside {
  -o-animation: slide 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: slide 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: slide 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: slide 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1" class="sidetoside">
  I'm a div! I move!
  <p>
    I'm more text in the div!
  </p>
</div>
```

You can use [`AnimationEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent) to respond to changes in the animation as well.

Comment: When using CSS animations, if I remove the class from the div using JS and give the class to a clone of that div will the new div (with the added class) continue moving from the other divs position if I set its current position via JS?

Comment: I have made a small edit which I believe addresses your comment.

Comment: This works perfectly when I add the webkit keyframes, however, the cloned element does not carry on from where the old element was. I.e. I want the newly created element to carry on from the middle of the screen moving to the left (if that's the position the old element was in). So if the old elem is 200px from the left moving to the right, the new element needs to be 200px from the left and start moving to the right while the old element just stops. I hope that's clear. 6:20am here.